# How can I find the cheapest private hotel room (as opposed to a bed in a dorm) using online tools?

Tags: budget, online-resources, accommodation, hotels

I tried the standard tools like [Kayak](http://www.kayak.co.uk/hotels) or [Momondo](http://hotels.momondo.co.uk), but there the cheapest option is always a bed in a dormitory. In particular I was searching for Amsterdam and the first few pages of results (sorted by price ascending) were full of dorms, making the tools useless in practice. How can I efficiently filter on the fact that I want a private room (for whatever number of people I enter)?

Comment: The answers so far seem to be thinking you're looking for a private room in a hostel, but you're actually looking for a *hotel* search that isn't cluttered with hostel dorm rooms, right?

Comment: I am looking for a private room somewhere, might be a hostel or a regular hotel. As you said, I don't want the search to be cluttered with dorms.

Answer (score 6):

On several of the hostel booking sites you can filter by room type, but this doesn't really filter the dorms away.

On [Hostelbookers](http://www.hostelbookers.com) you can do a search and then sort by 'Private room price (low to high)' which gives you the lowest private room prices first and you can ignore the shared prices which are still listed.

Answer (score 4):

[Booking.com](https://www.booking.com/) has this functionality. Search for hotels in a given city, then sort by price:

[image]

Booking.com will then offer you to exclude shared rooms:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work.  When selecting hotels it still shows dorm listings at dorm prices.  There is no option on booking.com to tell it to show private rooms only.

Answer (score 3):

Almost every hotel and hostel booking site allows you to filter/sort to identify private rooms.

This is possible on hostel sites, like [Hostelbookers](http://www.hostelbookers.com/), [HostelWorld](http://www.hostelworld.com/), and on hotel sites like [Booking.com](https://www.booking.com/).

Of course, not every hostel has private rooms, but most modern ones these days offer that option, and certainly hotels will allow this.

Comment: Go go Hostelworld, check the room type 'Single Room' (only), this doesn't make a difference to the results, they are still full of dorms because these places also offer singles.

Comment: Could you edit your comment? I don't really understand what you're saying.  I just tried it for [New York](http://www.hostelworld.com/search?search_keywords=New+York%2C+USA&country=USA&city=New-York) and it worked fine.

Comment: In my tests on HostelWorld I saw the same listed hostels for various room types. But I can now can confirm that it makes a difference. Make sure you sort by 'Price'.

Comment: Cool :) Glad I wasn't seeing things :)

Comment: Checking hostelbookers, and the functionality is a bit sh1t to be honest, because I selected 1 person, and it sorts by the per person price of the cheapest private option (which is usually private 8 person or something ridiculous)

Comment: He's asking about hotel rooms anyway, not hostels with private rooms. I'm only familiar with the hostel booking sites though and have never used a hotel booking site so I'm not familiar with the differences. Also most of these sites I've used also allow you to filter by price. If you set your minimum price to something about 10 or 15 euro or whatever the typical dormitory price is for the part of the world you're looking at, then you won't see most of the stuff you don't want.

Comment: Not possible on booking.com.  No such option for private room in the filter or the sort.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Hostelz.com](http://www.hostelz.com) to search by either dorm beds or private rooms (in fact, you have to choose one or the other, it always searches dorm beds and private rooms separately).  It's also possible to filter by room/bed type on Hostelworld (I think that feature was added recently), but it still isn't possible on some of the other hostel booking websites.  Hostelz.com searches all of the hostel booking sites at once (similar to what sites like Kayak let you do for hotels and airfare, but for hostels), so it will show you the lowest price for a private room or dorm bed from across all of the booking sites.  To order the results by price, look for "Order By:" on the left side and choose "Price".

There is definitely a big difference between wanting a private room and dorm room. I'm not sure why all of the hostel sites don't make that differentiation when searching for availability and prices.

Disclaimer: Just to be clear, I am posting this as a representative of Hostelz.com, so my opinions are probably at least a little biased towards the particular way our site does things.

Comment: Worth mentioning if you're affiliated with the site. A couple of (good) posts with the same site makes some people spam-nervous.

Comment: (Note: It's fine to be affiliated, people just ask that you declare so)

Comment: No problem, I'll add a note about that.

Answer (score -1):

Explore [https://www.PrivateRooms.Net](https://www.privaterooms.net).
I've developed this solution specifically to address this issue.
I hope it helps.
For the best experience, use it on a PC.
If you're on mobile, consider using the 'PC view' option.

Comment: Are you connected to this site? If so, you have to say so in your answer.

Comment: this sounds very, very spammy

Comment: Thanks for sharing, please edit the post to show you are not a spammer.

Comment: thank you very much